# how do i keep the default button tapped effect in a rounded button in android studio?

Tags: android

i want to create a rounded corner button in android studio while keeping the tapped effect as shown in this gif: (shown at the login button)
[image]

(sorry i cant post images due to low reputation count)

this is the xml code i'm using for the rounded button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/LogInWithFacebook"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="81dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners"
    android:text="Log in with Facebook"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#3B5998"/>
        <stroke android:color="#3B5998" android:width="2dp" />
        <!--corners allow us to make the rounded corners button-->
        <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

how can i make the login button effect for the rounded button? any help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Try this http://michaelevans.org/blog/2015/05/07/android-ripples-with-rounded-corners/

Comment: thank you, that should help me if i need a bigger button @Ankita